# How do I sympy pretty print without new lline?

Tags: python-3.x, math, sympy

How do I smp.pprint without a newline?
So I can put a '=' sign between the two smp.pprint functions.

```
import sympy as smp

Um, x = smp.symbols('Um wt', positive = True, real=True)


f = (Um * smp.sin(x)) / smp.pi


smp.pprint(smp.Integral(f, (x, 0, smp.pi)))


smp.pprint(smp.integrate(f, (x, 0, smp.pi)))
```

I tried format what just gives me Integral(Um*sin(wt)/pi, (wt, 0, pi)) and pformat what doesn't exist in sympy.

Comment: You can use sympy's `pretty` function to get the string and then do what you want with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use something like `pprint(Eq(Integral(x,(x,0,1)),integrate(x,(x,0,1))))` to print an expression showing the unevaluated and evaluated form of an integral.

But to answer your question, you can capture the string produced by pprint, strip the newline, and add it to another string:

```py
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import capture
>>> lhs = capture(lambda: pprint(Integral(x,(x,0,1)))).rstrip('\n')
>>> rhs = capture(lambda: pprint(integrate(x,(x,0,1))))
>>> print('%s = %s' % (lhs, rhs))
```

But this naive approach will not handle the alignment of the expressions. I would recommend using the `Eq` form to do this automatically for you. Otherwise, you could dive into the string typesetting algorithms that SymPy offers.